# "Unkown option 'fullname'" while trying to debug [C++][Code::Blocks]

Tags: codeblocks

Whenever I start the debugger for Code::Blocks, it just displays an "Unknown option 'fullname'" messagebox. I tried re-installing Code::Blocks, rebooting, etc.
Here's the log:

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\Users\Wiktor\Desktop\Algorytmy\szaszlyk\
Adding source dir: C:\Users\Wiktor\Desktop\Algorytmy\szaszlyk\
Adding file: C:\Users\Wiktor\Desktop\Algorytmy\szaszlyk\bin\Debug\szaszlyk.exe
Changing directory to: C:/Users/Wiktor/Desktop/Algorytmy/szaszlyk/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe -fullname -quiet  -args C:/Users/Wiktor/Desktop/Algorytmy/szaszlyk/bin/Debug/szaszlyk.exe
done
Debugger finished with status 1
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\Users\Wiktor\Desktop\Algorytmy\szaszlyk\
Adding source dir: C:\Users\Wiktor\Desktop\Algorytmy\szaszlyk\
Adding file: C:\Users\Wiktor\Desktop\Algorytmy\szaszlyk\bin\Debug\szaszlyk.exe
Changing directory to: C:/Users/Wiktor/Desktop/Algorytmy/szaszlyk/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe -fullname -quiet  -args C:/Users/Wiktor/Desktop/Algorytmy/szaszlyk/bin/Debug/szaszlyk.exe
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger finished with status 1
```

Edit 1: Resetting settings by deleting the %appdata%/CodeBlocks folder didn't work.
Edit 2: Changing the settings worked! Thank you very, very much HolyBlackCat!

Comment: For some reason your codeblocks.exe is set as a debugger executable, instead of gdb.exe. Either find the appropriate setting, or reset all settings by deleting `%appdata%/CodeBlocks`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure debugger application properly. First of all make sure that you have [GDB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/gdb/) installed.

Then go to **Settings->Debugger** and check that path to debugger is correct.

[image: Access to debugger settings configuration]
[image: Entering debugger executable path]